# tsrange(timestamp without time zone, timestamp with time zone)

Tags: postgresql, дата, timestamp

Добрый день, сообщество!
Есть в базе вьюха, которая берет данные в зависимости от диапазонов. Проблема в том, что сравниваются поля с разными типами(timestamp, date, timestamptz). Использую tsrange() и внутри него изменяю тип (::timestamp). Смена типа происходит, но что-то переводится в timestamp, что-то в timestamptz, почему это происходит не знаю. Как победить это и привести все к timestamp? Или какой способ использовать для универсального сравнения этих типов? (Типы полей в таблицах менять не могу).

Мой пример:

```
tsrange(t1.start_date,t1.end_date) @>   tsrange(coalesce(docPos.start_date::timestamp,dStartDate::timestamp),coalesce(docPos.end_date::timestamp,dEndDate::timestamp));
```

Если кидаете ссылки, прошу указать на что именно стоит обратить внимание.
Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем привел все к timestamptz и сравниваю в этом формате. Для меня это приемлемо.